# How to call a function

Tags: javascript, function, call, external

I've been looking for an answer to this question for 4 hours now, with no success.

Well, what I'm trying to do execute a function that does something if the user is using a certain browser.

I have the script used for detecting the browser, version, and OS in the head section of the page, and it works.

If I use the code below in the body of my page it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome")
{
   document.write("You're using Chrome")
}
else
{
    document.write("You're not using Chrome")
}
</script>
```

But if I put the code in an external script sheet, how do I use it?
I tried putting it in a function and calling that function on load by using this code.

```
<body onload="BrowserDetect();">
```

Note that the external script sheet is called in the head section of my page.

And this is the code in the external script sheet.

```
function BrowserDetect()
{
    if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome")
    {
        document.write("You're using Chrome")
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("You're not using Chrome")
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's the exact same code that worked when it was in the body of the web page. But when it's put in a function and called on load, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Browser sniffing is usually a bad idea (unless it's used for a "hey, use a better browser"-style message)

Comment: Does any error occurs? What output into javascript console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have named the called method the same as the `BrowserDetect` object you use.

Try

```
function BrowserDetectMethod()
{
    if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome")
    {
        document.write("You're using Chrome")
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("You're not using Chrome")
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
<body onload="BrowserDetectMethod();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of the function to something other than BrowserDetect.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem I was having from the beginning was that my scripts worked if I had them on the page, but I wanted them in an external style sheet, and if I had them in an external script sheet, the scripts didn't work. So I found out how to fix it, and I'll list below everything I did to make everything listed above work perfectly.

For those of you wondering how I detected the browser, I got it from this site: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html.
That works sooooooooo much better **and** easier detecting it using normal javascript.

First of all, the function should be named something other than BrowserDetect; I named it BrowserDetectMethod, like suggested by Gaby.

And second, if I am going to include the function in an external style sheet, the external style sheet needs to be called at the **bottom** of the page. Not in the head of the page like I was trying.

Third:

I decided the best way to browser sniff was to find the browsers I wanted to contact, not the ones I didn't. (since there are any number of browsers out there and I only wanted to contact three)

However, using the above method, I couldn't do that because this code doesn't work:

```
function BrowserDetectMethod()
{
    if (BrowserDetect.browser != "Chrome" && BrowserDetect.browser && "Safari" ||BrowserDetect.browser && "Firefox" )
    {
        document.write("You're not using a supported browser");
    }
    else
    {
         document.write("You're using a supported browser");
    }
}
```

The reason that code doesn't work is because it can't contain more than one "and" logical operator in the if statement.

So I had to achieve the desired affect by nesting if statements like so:

```
function BrowserDetectMethod()
{
    if (BrowserDetect.browser != "Chrome")
    {
        if(BrowserDetect.browser != "Firefox")
        {
            if(BrowserDetect.browser != "Safari")
            {
                document.write("You're not using a supported Browser");
            }
            else
            {
                document.write("You're using a supported Browser");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("You are using a supported Browser");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("You are using a supported Browser");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use multiple logical operators. You just have not written it correctly..  So use `var b = BrowserDetect.browser; if( b != 'Safari' && b != 'Firefox' && b != 'Chrome') {// supported} else {//not supported}`